# Java operators ||, -, /, +

Tags: java, operators

```
public class Program1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int s = 55; int c = 10;

       System.out.println( s-s/c*c );
       System.out.println( true || false ); 
       System.out.println( 9/5*c+32 );  
    }
}
```

The outcome:
5
true
42

1.Can someone explain why first println outcome is 5 and consistent with 's' number last digit?? like if I change 's' to 1012 the answer will be 2. Why?

2.true or false. answer is true. Why? it's like asking yes or no? -yes...

3.that math make no sense to me. Someone explain to me how in the world it is equal 42?

Comment: 55/10=5; 5*10=50 ;55-50=5

Comment: Order of predence...

Comment: Read about the order of precedence of arithmetic operation.
As to your question about the boolean expression. Yes "yes or no" is yes. (are you a human OR are you older than 1000 years old) is yes because you are a human

Comment: Since this is clearly converting Celsius temperatures to Fahrenheit, you probably want to know that if you change that last expression to `1.8 * c + 32` it will work as you want it to.

Comment: nice I didn't even noticed that it is fahrenheit conversion. I guys my proff already introducing the use of java in code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Can someone explain why first println outcome is 5 and consistent with 's' number last digit?? like if I change 's' to 1012 the answer will be 2. Why?

Because of operator precedence. Here it is with parens:

```
s - ((s / c) * c)
```

So `s / c` is `5` because these are `int` values, any fractional result is dropped. Then `5 * c` is `50`, and then `55 - 50` is `5`.

> 2.true or false. answer is true. Why? it's like asking yes or no? -yes...

Because `||` is true if either of its operands is true, and false otherwise. It's not relevant here, but it's also *short-circuited*, meaning that if the left-hand expression is `true`, the right-hand expression is never evaluated. Again, not relevant here, but it would be if the expressions had side-effects, like for instance `foo() || bar()` where the methods have side-effects: `foo` is always called, but `bar` is only called if `foo`'s result is `false`.

> 3.that math make no sense to me. Someone explain to me how in the world it is equal 42?

Again precedence:

```
((9 / 5) * c) + 32
```

So `9 / 5` is `1` because these are `int` values (any fractional result is dropped). Then `1 * c` is `10`, and `10 + 32` is `42`.

Answer (score 0):

A
java operates for arithmetic operations from left to right and solve  first one which  have higher precedence  in your question / and * have similar precedence so java will used left to right association , it will solve s/ c first , then multiply by c  then this term is subtracted from s because  + , _ have lower precedence . 
B  || is OR operator 
 true or(||) false is always true
  true and(&) false is always false
C  left to right with higher precedence 
    9 / 5  = 1 ignore the remainder
   1* c= 10   because c is given in ur program is 10
  10+32 = 42